# A very fun integration problem: Solving for $a$ in $\displaystyle\int_0^2(xe^a+ax)dx=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, exponentiation

So I was bored, and decided to look back at some of my old questions (including my deleted questions). After a while, I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4691666/solving-for-x-in-int-02xtdt-3) question of mine (not deleted), and decided to create this integral problem based off it$$\int_0^2(xe^a+ax)dx=0$$which I thought that I might be able to solve. Here is my attempt at doing so:$$\int_0^2(xe^a+ax)dx=0\implies2e^a+2a-1=0$$and now to solve our non-algebraic boi:$$2e^a+2a-1=0\implies e^a+a-0.5=0\\\implies e^a=-a+0.5\\\implies1=(-a+0.5)e^{-a}\\\implies e^{1/2}=(-a+0.5)e^{-a+0.5}\\\implies W(e^{1/2})=-a+0.5\\\implies a=0.5-W(e^{1/2})\\\approx-6.38905$$

---

---

### My question

---

Did I solve this non-algebraic boi correctly, or what could I do to solve it correctly?

---

Also note that the reason we use the main branch of Lambert's $W$ function here is because we have a real solution to this problem.

Comment: Where did your $-1$ come from in the first step?

Comment: You computed the integral incorrectly.

Comment: @N.Owad Actually, now that I think about it, I must've accidently evaluated that incorrectly, not sure where it came from

Comment: @CrSb0001 Are you planning to fix it?

Comment: @Gary No, I've already posted it, so it wouldn't make sense for me to edit the question to make the integration correct. Besides, it's already been answered, and as today's kids would put it, I'm just going to have to take the L and move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a=-W(1)$$
$$(e^a+a)\int_0^2xdx=(e^a+a)(\frac{x^2}{2}) \vert_0^2 $$
$$2e^a+2a=0$$
$$e^a+a=0$$
$$e^a=-a$$
$$1=-ae^{-a}$$
$$a=-W(1)$$